# Android Video Capture take more file size -expo-image-picker

Tags: android, react-native, expo

While capturing the video using expo image picker for android even the quality: 0.1 file size not yet compressed, For the latest Android 10 and 11 less than 2 min video recording its take more than 300 to 400 MB. Is there is any way to reduce the file size

```
let result = await ImagePickerExpo.launchCameraAsync({
mediaTypes: ImagePickerExpo.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
aspect: [4, 3],
quality: 0.1,
exif: true,
allowsEditing: true,
videoMaxDuration: 600,
videoQuality: 1,
videoExportPreset: ImagePickerExpo.VideoExportPreset.MediumQuality,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Expo SDK doesn't provide a video compression package out of the box. You need to use third-party packages.

Video compression packages rely on native code which will not work with managed Expo Go projects.

You need to build a [custom Expo Go app with the pre-compiled](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id0Im72UN6w&t=25s) native module.

You can use https://github.com/Shobbak/react-native-compressor for  compression

Comment: Thanks for your response, After the video capture I am using a video compressor. while compressing the video takes too much time for that reason, on capture video is there any way to reduce video quality to reduce the size is better than the video compressor. For IOS its working good ,issue is only on android